# Ender 5 SKR Mini E3 -- After Heating the Hot End Assembly Runs into the side of the printer

Tags: marlin, firmware, creality-ender-5, skr-mini-e3

So I got the SKR mini E3 for my Ender 5 after hearing all the positive reviews.

When it arrives I plug everything in, make sure it's secure and test the axis... they all worked correctly.

I then tested auto home... everything worked.

I then tested the heating... everything worked again.

Finally, I go to do a test print-- it heats up and then homes. When it is finished heating, the hot end assembly starts moving slowly until it goes into the corner and contacts the side of the printer. Obviously, I turned it off right away.

Currently, I am uncertain whether it is a firmware issue, a board issue, or something else? If anyone could please help me solve this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It means the endstop is not working. Assuming no mechanical changes to where it's mounted, either it's not connected to the right place on the board or the firmware is not processing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the way Creality has defined the origin of the printer. Usually, the origin of the printer is at the front left when facing the printer. Creality has chosen to set the origin in their default Creality configuration at the back right.

Vanilla Marlin (Ender 5 configuration) has the origin at the front left. When facing the printer this makes more sense. Do note that there are printers with the origin in the middle and in the back right location, but these are outnumbered by far in preference of the front left location.

This means that when you switch boards you need to carefully look at the settings of the endstops and the definitions of the being min or max endstops and inverting or not of the steppers.

Answer (score -1):

So I found an answer on Reddit when I asked the same question: It actually had to do with the homing -- basically, it was starting at 220, 220 instead of 0,0, which resulted in when the print started for it to head straight into the corner. In order to counter this, I had to change some of the firmware. Everything works now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please expand the answer with the changes you made, others may benefit from it. This answer doesn't explain well enough to fix it. Thanks!